# No puedo clickar en un Radio Button - Selenium Salesforce

Tags: java, selenium

Estoy intentando hacer click sober un elemento radio button en selenium en una página web de salesforce. Adjunto imagen de la página y del elemento a inspeccionar.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uCIv.jpg

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

Puedo localizar perfectamente el elemento en la página,`((//input[@type=\"radio\"][@value=\"IHT_Healthcare_Group\"])//parent::span)[1]"` pero obtengo siempre el mismo error a pesar de haber intentado varias soluciones...

He intentado realizar la operacion con "Actions", pero obtengo el mismo resultado.

He buscado la existencia de iframes en la página, pero no hay, por lo que parece que ese tampoco es el problema.

También intenté:

```
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) DriverManager.getDriver();
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", DriverManager.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("((//input[@type=\"radio\"][@value=\"IHT_Healthcare_Group\"])//parent::span)[1]")));
```

Con esta última, no sale ningún error, pero tampoco se realiza el click (en la web no se ve el elemento clickado).

Cual puede ser el problema?

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Traduce tu pregunta, de lo contrario terminará [cerrada](/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 0):

buenas noches, ese problema persiste a un nivel de usuario en las org mediante los tabs vistos en la captura de pantalla. Cuando se automatizan las pruebas a traves de java(selenium), se recomienda crear una clase global en la estructura del framework que cierre los tabs a nivel background del test, antes de completar formularios y demás. Asi mismo si se tiene una bateria de pruebas, permanece esa verificacion de que los tabs esten cerrados en cada ejecucion.
En correlacion con respecto al XPATH, al tener esos tabs abiertos, va a encontrar los resultados en el primer tab, y no donde se ve en la imagen.
En caso del selector recomiendo la Extension:
SelectorsHub
Saludos!

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/333476)